# How to disable lines around text and explanations in Sublime Text

Tags: line, sublimetext, word-wrap

I have these lines around text and explanations popping up annoyingly. 
Is there a way to turn these off?

[image: sublimeText]

I tried to look in settings and to adjust them but nothing works out.

*P.S. ignore the code, it's just for example*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White lines surrounding code like that are generally indicative of something like a code linter or other similar tool giving you an indication that there might be something wrong with the code (such as not following a code convention of some sort). The code explanation is a popup showing you the arguments and documentation for whatever function or method you're working on.

Both of these things are something that Sublime doesn't do on its own; you have installed a package of some sort that provides this capability.

If you were looking in the regular Sublime settings (`Preferences.sublime-settings`) for options that control this, they won't be there. In order to configure these away you would need to determine the package that you installed that's doing this and then configure that package not to do it or, if that's not possible, remove it.

If you use `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User` from the menu, you can inspect the `installed_packages` setting to see what third party packages you installed and investigate which one of them is doing this.

Possible packages that do something like this would be `Jedi` or one of the `Anaconda` packages; essentially anything that says that it provides code support and assistance for Python is a candidate here.

Once you find the package in question, you can look in it's settings directly to see if you can turn the features you don't want off; failing that only removing the package will stop it from displaying these things.

Comment: It was an Anaconda package that caused the bracket problem.
To solve the white-lines-problem you have to go:

Sublime Text > preferences > Package Settings > Anaconda > Settings - Default
Use CTRL + F keyboard combination and find and change these lines:
 "anaconda_linter_mark_style": "none",
 "anaconda_linting": false,

Answer (score 1):

These lines are called linting. **Linting is the process of running a program that will analyse code for potential errors.**

In sublime text it occurs usually because of some packages that you have installed...

In your case, it is actually the anaconda package and some other packages. It can be removed easily in a few simple steps.

In the sublime text window press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to open a command pallete and then type the name of the package. I typed **anaconda** because it is the one giving me these lintings so there will be an option **Disable linting on this file**. Just click on it, as shown in this picture [image].